# Spacing between forms in HTML

Tags: html

I'm new to HTML, this being my first project. I'm trying to design a simple calculator, identical to this image.

[image]

The problem I'm having is I can't find a simple way to put spacing between the labels i.e "term, interest rate" and the input boxes meaning the layout looks poor. The easiest I've found is adding loads of &nbsp's but that seems ludicrous.

For example in the code below how can I get spacing between the "Term" and the input box?

```html
<form>
                <label>
                    Term <input name ="term" type ="text"/>
                </label>
            </form>
```

Comment: Look into CSS  margins and padding.

Comment: You could also use a `table` arrangement, in addition to the answer accepted in the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.table tr td{
    text-align:right;
}

/*this sets padding space */
.table tr td{
  padding-top:10px;
}
```

```html
<form>

 <table class="table">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <label> Term  </label>
    </td>
    <td><input name ="term" type ="text"/></td>
   </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <label> Rate Blah Blah  </label>
    </td>
    <td><input name ="blahblah" type ="text"/></td>
   </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

you can use it like this